# JSON response object more organized

Tags: json, httprequest

My question might seem silly but for example:

I want to get all the movies from ['The Movie DB'](https://www.themoviedb.org/); they provided me with the `api_key` and a link, i.e: `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key="my_api"`. When I pass this link into firefox / chrome ( with my api instead of "my_api" ) I get a bunch of JSON objects and I can't really distinguish them.

Is there any way that I can organize the JSON object in something more readable in the sense of organized?

I get [this](https://ibb.co/T8pBCFB) but I want it [organized](https://ibb.co/4KZhV2h)

Any idea?

Comment: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is a program designed to test/develop api calls. It formats the json output pretty nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has a JSON viewer as you describe built in. Are you using a current version? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer

There are plugins for other browsers. For example for Chrome look at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/json